# c - understand if pipe/fifo is full

Tags: c, pipe, named-pipes, systems-programming

I have a fifo opened as RDWR(for communicate process-process) and pipes(process-thread), how can I understand when I reach pipes or fifos limit? When I try to write more than 64 KB it just wait in write().

Comment: That how pipes work. If the pipe gets full when you write to it, `write` will block until data is "removed" from the pipe.

Comment: Open non-blocking and test the result of `write`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use non-blocking mode:

```
pipe2(fds, O_NONBLOCK);
```

Or if you need to do it after the pipe was created:

```
int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
```

Now when you read or write and the operation cannot complete immediately, it will return.  You can then use `select()` or `poll()` to find out when reading or writing is possible again (or you can just busy-wait).

Comment: And it will return `-1` and set `errno` to `EAGAIN` — POSIX [`write()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html)
says:  _A write request for {PIPE_BUF} or fewer bytes shall have the following effect: if there is sufficient space available in the pipe, write() shall transfer all the data and return the number of bytes requested. Otherwise, write() shall transfer no data and return -1 with errno set to [EAGAIN]._

Comment: I should note that the description I quoted applies specifically to a pipe or FIFO with the `O_NONBLOCK` flag set — read the rest of the specification for the behaviour under other circumstances.